# Glide Does not use Cached Image

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

Hi I am using Glide to load image and after following many posts I tried to implement Glide caching using 
`RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).centerCrop()`

`Glide.with(mContext)
      .load(imageUrl)
      .transition(ImageUtil.crossFadeTransition())
      .apply(ImageUtil.requestOptionsForSlider())
      .listener(glideRequestListner)
      .into(imageView)`

My knowledge is that if I use `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` then the above `Glide` image loading code will automatically use cache if available, or download if not, right?

But I see everytime the code is called, (checking my internet speed meter) that it is always fetching/downloading from the given url (even though I can see the app memory size is increasing).

I even tried this code also-

`val future: FutureTarget<File> = Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .downloadOnly(500, 500)`

Nothing seems to work

What should I do so that `Glide` uses cache if available?What is wrong with my conception about the caching implementation? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is downloading again ? did you try disabling internet just before loading the images ?
Otherwise, is your image URL always the same for the same image ? (as Glide uses it as a cache key).
You can use this in the following calls to check if images are in cache:

`Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
  .into(imageView);`

Comment: yes , I tried that, but as I Mentioned , i check the internet meter as it was downloading
and also not showing anything when internet is disabled

Comment: .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true) is not returning anything , getting no image

Comment: as i can see that everytime imageurl is being changed(suffix signature change) , so  what should I do that glide understands they are the same image

Comment: you should find a way to uniquely identify your image and give it a signature... a name or id of your object etc.
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-keys